# similarity measure for 3D point sets

Tags: 3d, point, similarity

assume i have two sets of points each containing 20 points in 3d space. 
I'm looking for a measure that calculates their similarity in terms of geometric shape. I've tried hausdorff distance but i need something more representative.any help is appreciated.

Comment: Define "more representative".

Comment: if two sets are similar in shape, the measure should be high and if they are not, the measure should be low. i want a method that measures the difference between different geometric shapes better.i hope this clarify 'more representative'